# Google Cloud Run - Stockfish causes deploy failure

Tags: python, google-cloud-run, stockfish

recently been trying to get Stockfish to run and receive HTTP requests on a web server and ran into an issue. importing and initilizing stockfish causes the deploy to fail, when locally ran it runs perfectictly fine but as soon as I go to deploy it I get

```
Invalid filter resource.type="cloud_run_revision"resource.labels.service_name="main"resource.labels.revision_name="main-00003-cuf"
```

To get stockfish into the project I compiled it like normal and the code used to initalize it is

```
From stockfish import Stockfish

stockfish = Stockfish(path="PATH")
```

These 2 lines cause the deploy to fail, I know this becasue as soon as I remove these 2 lines the deploy works.

Here is the link to the Stockfish doc https://pypi.org/project/stockfish/

Any help would be much appreciated!

I haven't been able to find anyone else who has ran into an issue like this but im sure there has been or it's a simple fix and im just dumb.